# How to get an async function to return a text

Tags: javascript, async-await

Why do async turn a return value in to "`[object Promise]`"

This is the code that I would like to work....

```
function foo() {
    let res = bar("HELLO")
    console.log(res)
}

async function bar (text) {
    text = text + await getData();
    return (text)
}

function getData () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Do a lot of stuff to find myResult
        resolve(myResult)
    })
}
```

So my question is this... how come this returns `HELLO`

```
function foo() {
    let res = bar("HELLO")
    console.log(res)
}

function bar (text) {
    return (text)
}
```

and this returns `[object Promise]`

```
function foo() {
    let res = bar("HELLO")
    console.log(res)
}

async function bar (text) {
    return (text)
}
```

How do I get the async function to return the text?

Comment: `async` functions always return Promises. You must `await` them or call `.then` on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.then()`. Try this.

```js
async function bar (text) {
    return text;
}
var test = bar("hello");

test.then((value) => console.log(value));
```

Comment: Damn it!! I forgot THEN!! hahaha - you are right @Joven28  :)
how embarrassing LOL .

Answer (score 5):

An async function return value is automatically wrapped in a Promise. For you to unwrap that using the async/await syntax, you again need to await that function.

So in your case:

```
function foo() {
    let res = bar("HELLO")
    console.log(res)
}
```

Needs to become:

```
async function foo() {
    let res = await bar("HELLO")
    console.log(res)
}
```

or you can deal with it in the promise-chaining way:

```
function foo() {
    bar("HELLO").then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: Better answer, handles both `await` and `.then`